# Isekai manga where whole class is summoned and one of the students, who was previously summoned, kills the princess

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

So I saw a few panels on a TikTok and can't remember the name and I know it's not *Isekai Shoukan wa Nidome Desu*. But the main character gets summoned, with his class this time, and finds out the princess betrayed him the last time he was there. He then kills her and her guards.

Comment: Random guess: "The Whole Class was Transported Along, But I’m Hiding My Strength By Masquerading as a Merchant". Protagonist summoned twice, with entire class. Princess is an awful person. He doesn't kill her within the first 3 chapters, but it's possible he'll do it later or something.